# configure error in graphtool for CGAL

Tags: configure, cgal, graph-tool

I am trying to install graphtool 2.2.35, I have installed all required library and  verified that it is working.
However when I run ./configure then I  got the following error:

checking:
:
:

```
Using python version: 2.7.5
===========================
checking for boostlib >= 1.53.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::Python library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_python... yes
checking whether the Boost::Iostreams library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams... no
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams-mt... no
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams-mt-py2.5... no
checking whether the Boost::Regex library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... yes
checking whether the Boost::Graph library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_graph... yes
checking for main in -lCGAL... no
checking whether to cgal debbuging with valgrind...... no
checking python module: numpy... yes
checking for /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h... yes
checking python module: scipy... yes
checking /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/object.h usability... yes
checking /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/object.h presence... yes
checking for /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/object.h... yes
checking expat.h usability... yes
checking expat.h presence... yes
checking for expat.h... yes
checking CGAL/version.h usability... no
checking CGAL/version.h presence... no
checking for CGAL/version.h... no
configure: error: CGAL headers not found
```

I am using Linux centos 7
GCC 4.8
Boost 1_57_.0
Pyhton 2.7.5
CGAL 3.5
GMP 6

Could you please help me out? I have already spent twoo much time too figure it out bu no luck. your help in this regard would highly be appreciated

Comment: Obviously it is not finding CGAL. You say you have CGAL 3.5. How exactly did you install it and where?

Comment: thanks for your reply, it was in wrong directory, I have copy CGAL folder in /usr/include

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Ubuntu, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev
```

Comment: Could you add some detail to this post? Why should the OP use this command? What will the effects be? How does it pertain to the problem statement?